# Find minimal primary decompositions of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, primary-decomposition

(1) In $R = \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 -1)$, find a minimal primary decomposition of $(\bar{x}^2)$.

(2) In $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, find a minimal primary decomposition of $(6)$.

For (1), I know that
$$(\bar{x}^2) = (1 - \bar{y}^2)=\left((1-\bar{y})(1+\bar{y})\right)$$

Then
$$((1-\bar{y})(1+\bar{y}))=(1-\bar{y})\cap(1+\bar{y}) $$
and $(1-\bar{y}), (1+\bar{y})$ are prime ideals in $R$,

since
$$R \cong \mathbb{R}[\bar{x}, \bar{y}] \text{ and } R/(1-\bar{y}) \cong \mathbb{R}[\bar{x}, \bar{y}]/(1-\bar{y})\cong \mathbb{R}[\bar{x}]$$ which is an integral domain and similarly for the case of $(1+\bar{y})$.

Then both of these ideals are primary ideals, too.

But for (2), I don’t know how to proceed.

All I’ve done is:

$$(6) = (2\cdot3)=((1+\sqrt{-5})\cdot(1-\sqrt{-5}))$$

And I’ve searched this question but all I’ve found was about ideal factorization.

It is written as a product of ideals, not as an intersection of primary ideals.

Is that factorization same with primary decomposition?

Any comment will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You might be missing the image of $x$ when you say "primes" in your first primary decomposition. For the second one, you could to proceed similarly in $Z[x]/(x^2+5)$ which is isomorphic to the given ring in (2). In general, I believe showing the equality involving intersections is a usually non-trivial task.

Comment: @Youngsu Thank you for comment. I'll try agian considering your suggestion.

Comment: @Youngsu Is it $(\bar{x}^2) = (1-\bar{y})\cap(1+\bar{y})\cap(\bar{x})$?

Comment: Is $R=\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ an integral domain? Because $x\cdot x=x^2=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), I'm still working on.

For (2), I think I found a solution.

Here it is:

$Claim: (6) = (2) \cap (3, 1 + \sqrt{-5}) \cap (3 ,1 - \sqrt{-5})$

Consider $(2, 1+ \sqrt{-5}), (3, 1+ \sqrt{-5}$) and $(3, 1-\sqrt{-5})$.
$(2, 1+ \sqrt{-5}) = (2, 1-\sqrt{-5})$,
since $2 - (1+\sqrt{-5}) = 1 - \sqrt{-5}\\$

And $(3, 1+\sqrt{-5})(3, 1-\sqrt{-5}) = (3)$.

We claim that $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.
Because $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 5)$,

\begin{align}
   \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/(2,1+\sqrt{-5}) &\simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,1+x,x^2+5) \\
   &\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(1+x, 1+x^2) \\
   &\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(1+x, (1+x)^2) \\
   &\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(1+x) ≃ \mathbb{Z}_2
\end{align}
This shows that $(2, 1+ \sqrt{-5})$ is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Similarly, we can show that $(3, 1+\sqrt{-5}),\ (3, 1-\sqrt{-5})$ are both maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Since $(2) = (2, 1+\sqrt{-5})^2$, This implies that $(2)$ is $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$-primary.

And $(3, 1+\sqrt{-5}) + (3, 1-\sqrt{-5}) = (1)$, so that
$$(3, 1+\sqrt{-5}) \cap  (3,1-\sqrt{-5}) = (3,1+\sqrt{-5})(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$$

Then we can prove our claim now.
\begin{align*}
   (6) = (2)\cdot(3) &= (2)\cap(3) \\
   &=(2) \cap \left((3,1+\sqrt{-5})\cdot(3, 1-\sqrt{-5})\right) \\
   &=(2) \cap  (3,1+\sqrt{-5}) \cap (3, 1-\sqrt{-5}) \\
   \end{align*}

$\sqrt{(2)}, \sqrt{(3,1+\sqrt{-5})}, \sqrt{(3, 1-\sqrt{-5})}$ are all distinct.
and none of three primary ideals $(2), (3, 1+\sqrt{-5}), (3, 1-\sqrt{-5})$ contains the intersection of the others.
This shows that this primary decomposition is indeed minimal.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: I would like you to explain to me the way you think of that problem so you can come up to the claim you did. Im trying to find a minimal prime decomposition of $<20>$ on $ℤ[\sqrt{-19}]$ but I cant think of how to claim something like what you did.

Comment: @GiorgosKosmas I think you should consider how 20 would be factorized in the ring you mentioned. My gut feeling tells me that $20 = 2^2 5 = (1+\sqrt{-19})(1-\sqrt{-19})$, so the primary ideals you want to find should be expressed as a combinations of the numbers appearing on the factorization of 20. I hope it will be helpful.