# Find the primary decomposition of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, primary-decomposition

I would like to find the minimal primary decompositions of, say, $(4)$ and $(1+\sqrt5)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. In [Find minimal primary decompositions of ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953873/find-minimal-primary-decompositions-of-ideals) there is a similar example, what troubles is that doesn't seem to exist any intuition as to why one would find that primary decomposition.

For my case:

For (4), I know that $(2,1+\sqrt{5})$ is a maximal ideal and $(2,1+\sqrt{5})^2=(4,2+2\sqrt{5})$, so I feel like this ideal will part of the primary decomposition but I can't seem to finish it.

For $(1+\sqrt{5})$, I'm also not sure what to do.

Comment: We have $4=-(1+\sqrt{5})(1-\sqrt{5})$. In fact $(4)$ is primary.